# Saving profile in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my app, I am writing some data, and I want to save it so that I can retrieve it later. How can I save it and where will it be saved?

Please suggest some ideas...

Comment: What type of data would you like to save?

Comment: `Speak that later.` Do you mean an audio file or text or what?

Comment: I think Dolphia means retrieve it later.

Comment: what  i meant is-my app will help user to write some data and save those data(in Text format or number format) which they will use later..These data will be able to talk..my app is for mute persons who can't talk..so their family members will save some personal info in teh app which they can use later on when they will confront the real world…am i clear?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to store it in a database using Core Data.  If you give more specifics I may be able to give a more specific answer.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults would be the obvious suggestion.

Other suggestions would be to write it to a .plist file in the documents directory or use core-data depending on how much you would want to save.

Comment: If it is any type of sensitive information, I would not suggest `NSUserDefaults`. It is too easy to get access to, even with very little knowledge of the iPhone file system. I cannot tell you how many twitter/other API keys I have found because they were saved in `NSUserDefaults`...

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III, valid point there. But then saving to the documents directory can also be accessed easily. I would suggest core-data as a secure method then.

Comment: Yes, core data is much more secure, however an encrypted plist / binary format is definitely the safest way to go, because he references `profile` in the title.